# web.config maxJsonLength issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I try to send large message json(with images) using HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync from one side and try get data in Controller using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc version="5.2.3".

When I send small messages everything is okey.

Move code details:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method<TRequest>(string url, TRequest request,
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers)
      {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandlerFactory.CreateHandler()))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoCache = true };
            AddHeadersToClient(client, headers);

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, request);
            ...
```

and on other side:

```
   public class MyController: Controller
   {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmailBody(string siteShortName, string templateName, RequestAcceptType acceptType, [DynamicJson] dynamic model) 
    {
        //Some logic
        return View(viewPath, model);
    }
...
```

And when sending message I get

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

According article [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config) I try to solve issue with different approches:

- added in web.config [section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/3878876)
- try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207539/3878876) in controller method
- try to add [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039031/3878876//) in Global.asax

And in all cases I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its strange to get the max lenght, but are you using base64 images? 
depending on quantity of images, you can easily get the max Json lenght just like that.

I can suggest a alternative to send large emails with images base64, you can create a view in html and parse with razor engine.

```
string view = Server.MapPath("~/Views/_YourView.cshtml");
string template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(view);
body = Razor.Parse(template, youmodel);
```